# Add path in Python to a Notebook

Tags: python, path, jupyter-notebook

What am I doing wrong here?

I cannot add a path to my Jupyter Notebook. I am stuck. Any of my attempts did not work at all.

`home_dir="\C:\Users\User\Desktop\"
data_dir=home_dir + "\C:\Users\User\Desktop\A Student's Guide to Python for Physical Modeling by KInder and Nelson\code"
data_set=np.loadtxt(data_dir + "HIVseries.csv", delimiter=',')`

Comment: `\C:\Users\User\Desktop\A Student's Guide to Python for Physical Modeling by KInder and Nelson\code` is an absolute file path, adding another root dir prefix makes it invalid.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy question, modify `\C:\Users\User\Desktop\A Student's Guide to Python for Physical Modeling by KInder and Nelson\code` to `C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\A Student's Guide to Python for Physical Modeling by KInder and Nelson\\code`.

Comment: Sorry, but my attempt to add "\\" did not work out. Thanks for your answer tho!

Answer (score 0):

Change the second line of your code as:

```
home_dir = "\C:\Users\User\Desktop\"
data_dir = home_dir + "A Student's Guide to Python for Physical Modeling by KInder and Nelson\code"
data_set = np.loadtxt(data_dir + "HIVseries.csv", delimiter=',')
```

Your code adds the home directory to the data directory. You don't to include the home again. Just providing the relative path would work.

What you were doing would make `data_dir` equal to `\C:\Users\User\Desktop\\C:\Users\User\Desktop\A Student's Guide to Python for Physical Modeling by KInder and Nelson\code` which is not a valid path.